# Win32 multiple dialogs command handler

Tags: c++, winapi

In my Win32 application I have multiple dialogs and am using the following macro to handle commands for all the dialogs:

```
HANDLE_MSG(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, OnCommand);
```

I would like the following code to close all the dialogs except for IDD_DIALOG1:

```
case IDOK:
case IDCANCEL:
    EndDialog(hWnd, 0);
```

How to modify the above code to differentiate among dialogs?

Comment: Did you try cycle the EndDialog with the number of dialgs?

Comment: I am afraid not. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. The resource ID is used to create the dialog only. It is not retained, or attached to the dialog itself. It's gone, once `CreateDialog` (and relatives) returns. You'll have to keep track of IDs and corresponding `HWND`s yourself, if you want to solve this. Relevant resource: [How can I recover the dialog resource ID from a dialog window handle?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050708-21/?p=34993/): *"It’s like asking, “Given a plate of food, how do I recover the original cookbook and page number for the recipe?” [...]"*

Comment: You could use a hidden control with a specific (unique) ID on the dialog in question, e.g. create a hidden static control with id `IDC_DIALOG1MARKER`; then as long as no other dialog has a control with that id you can identify the dialog with `if (GetDlgItem(hWnd, IDC_DIALOG1MARKER) != nullptr) { }`. But there are definitely better ways of doing this. And it's unusual to have a lot of dialogs sharing the same dialog procedure.